# Disabling Alt-Tab for Windows, but still allow it to be used?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, gaming

During my gaming, I am experiencing a slight problem.

My sprint is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> and another useful function (item drop) is bound to <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I often hit the two together, and my game exits...

Is there a way to disable Alt-Tab for Windows, but still allow my game to use it?

No, I cannot re-bind the keys. If you tell me to, an [irrelevant elephant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/the-comforting-death-message-tricky) will say hi to you.

Comment: What game is this? I would consult the forums of the games website if they have one.

Comment: I mostly have this issue in Minecraft, but it's also prevalent in Skyrim.

Comment: You can try the tutorials here http://www.howtogeek.com/194811/how-to-prevent-the-windows-key-alttab-and-sticky-keys-from-ruining-your-gaming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (free, open source) and remap Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if you want to keep your game keymap.

You may also look in game options for "disable alt-tab shortcut". Some games (StarCraft II for example) have feature like this.